# App crashes on devices with removable sd card when it is not inserted

Tags: android, android-sdcard

my application stores files received from other devices in the external storage. It works fine with devices with non removable sd cards

The issue is on galaxy tab4 when the external sd card is not inserted.

I am using the following line to get file path

```
String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/BFT/";
```

> What I want to do is if the external sd card is removable and not inserted I want to create the above mentioned directory in the device storage (Like 16 GB is provided in Galaxy s4).

I am confused because in galaxy s4 it is working fine but it is stored in this directory when using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/BFT/"

[This is where it is stored on S4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0LOj.png)

How to make it work on tab4 or any other device which may crash when external sd card is removable and not inserted and I used the above line.

> I just want a folder to be created on the device no matter what its storage architecture is. Specific code is appreciated or at least what is causing the error(I know directory is not found.But Why?).

Comment: You just check if ExternalStorage is available before you manipulate its directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the state of the External Storage Directory before using it

`getExternalStorageState()`
Returns the current state of the primary shared/external storage media.

```
Returns
one of MEDIA_UNKNOWN, MEDIA_REMOVED, MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, MEDIA_CHECKING, MEDIA_NOFS, MEDIA_MOUNTED, MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, MEDIA_SHARED, MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL, or MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE.
```

Also ExternalStorage doesn't always mean External

> *Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.*

For more information on [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: Got it...but in tab4 if it is not mounted....i still want to store it in device memory(16 gb in my case). I just want to store it any how even if the external storage is unavailable

Comment: You are creating a BFT folder before it exists on the device.

Comment: I tried creating that on the device storage. But it is not being found by using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory+"/BFT/" clearly because sd card is not mounted as you said. But what if i want to use that device storage?

Comment: `I tried creating that on the device storage.` show us how you created ?

Comment: Manually i mean (I created it manually). The folder already existed i just wanted to store inside it. In the device storage of galaxy tab4 i created this folder. But when i try saving files inside it ...the app crashes

Comment: This is hwo you create a folder, `String folder_main = "BFT";

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                folder_main);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }`

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory in case of galaxy tab points to the removable sd card. I want to store the files inside the pre existing folder in device storage provided by samsung. And I cant show you the logcat because the tab4 is used by my client ...I tested it on s4 and it is working fine .Please note that directory already exists...sorry i didn't clear it up before

Comment: seems like a permission issue, do you have the `write external storage` permission ?

Comment: only issue is...Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory in case of galaxy tab points to the removable sd card which is not inserted. can u tell me the path for internal device storage?

Comment: This is the way already. And there is app's internal memory which can be get through `getFilesDir()`

Comment: That is for internal storage and will be deleted along with the app....I want the files to be kept even after the app is deleted

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Environment.getExternalDirectory() returns removable sd card path on some devices while on others it displays the device storage (Both are external storages not internal).

To display the list of mounted external storage I used getStorageList() of this class and then selecting one external storage which was available.

```
public class StorageUtils {

private static final String TAG = "StorageUtils";

public static class StorageInfo {

    public final String path;
    public final boolean readonly;
    public final boolean removable;     
    public final int number;

    StorageInfo(String path, boolean readonly, boolean removable, int number) {
        this.path = path;
        this.readonly = readonly;
        this.removable = removable;         
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        if (!removable) {
            res.append("Internal SD card");
        } else if (number > 1) {
            res.append("SD card " + number);
        } else {
            res.append("SD card");
        }
        if (readonly) {
            res.append(" (Read only)");
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}

public static List<StorageInfo> getStorageList() {

    List<StorageInfo> list = new ArrayList<StorageInfo>();
    String def_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    boolean def_path_removable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
    String def_path_state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    boolean def_path_available = def_path_state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
                                || def_path_state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);
    boolean def_path_readonly = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);

    HashSet<String> paths = new HashSet<String>();
    int cur_removable_number = 1;

    if (def_path_available) {
        paths.add(def_path);
        list.add(0, new StorageInfo(def_path, def_path_readonly, def_path_removable, def_path_removable ? cur_removable_number++ : -1));
    }

    BufferedReader buf_reader = null;
    try {
        buf_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));
        String line;
        Log.d(TAG, "/proc/mounts");
        while ((line = buf_reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, line);
            if (line.contains("vfat") || line.contains("/mnt")) {
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                String unused = tokens.nextToken(); //device
                String mount_point = tokens.nextToken(); //mount point
                if (paths.contains(mount_point)) {
                    continue;
                }
                unused = tokens.nextToken(); //file system
                List<String> flags = Arrays.asList(tokens.nextToken().split(",")); //flags
                boolean readonly = flags.contains("ro");

                if (line.contains("/dev/block/vold")) {
                    if (!line.contains("/mnt/secure")
                        && !line.contains("/mnt/asec")
                        && !line.contains("/mnt/obb")
                        && !line.contains("/dev/mapper")
                        && !line.contains("tmpfs")) {
                        paths.add(mount_point);
                        list.add(new StorageInfo(mount_point, readonly, true, cur_removable_number++));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (buf_reader != null) {
            try {
                buf_reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

> This issue is faced when dealing with newer devices with more than one mount points for external storage like galaxy series of Samsung.